# how to override return to call button on keyguard password screen?

Tags: android

When the user use a screen lock security password (KEYGUARD), i manage to show the incoming call screen (using window flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED), when the call is in progress and the user push the back/home button we get the lock screen agin and the user can't end the call. (in Android default implementation there is a "return to call" button in the lock screen). so what sould i do in this case?